# Perl + Ajax - Emulate a Command Line via HTML?

Tags: html, ajax, perl

Is it possible (or, I suppose, practical) to use Perl with Ajax to create something similar to a command-line interface using HTML?

Essentially, I want to have a space on my web page where the user can type some command at the prompt, which would then get passed to my underlying Perl script, which would then be able to print back to this section of the webpage, get any interaction needed from the user, and then wait for another command.

I'm afraid this whole HTML thing is a touch outside my comfort zone, so I'm just looking to see if this is possible before I devote a whole bunch of time to something that's going to be a dead end!

Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely possible, it's been done for Ruby: http://tryruby.org/

Comment: Short answer: [yes, it's possible](http://uni.xkcd.com/).

Comment: Just be careful - there are a couple of tiny possible security issues in what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical Ajax example. You have input elements (e.g. input text line or textarea) to retrieve input. When you push a button or submit the form, javascript takes whatever you have input and packs it in a Ajax request to the server. The server receives whatever you typed, processes it and returns the output. This output is caught by your client side javascript program again (the "success" method of the ajax call if you're using jquery), and it uses DOM manipulation to replace a part of the website with the returned result.

Assuming you have a web server running already, there are many ways that web server can route a request to your perl script, but the "classical" (read "old") way of doing that was invoking the perl script using the CGI standard. There are better ways now (better protocols than CGI, or even complete application servers in your favourite programming language). Perl has Mojolicious, Catalyst or Dancer for instance, and probably more that I do not know about.

There should be enough keywords here to get you going...